# sorting Array of Objects

Tags: javascript

I have an Array like the following, how would I sort it by the keys of the objects it contains?

```
var myArray = [
    item : {

    },
    anotherItem : {

    }
];
```

**EDIT**

`myArray` is an Object not an Array. Does that change anything?

Comment: I don't think that's valid... =/

Comment: This is not valid [Javascript Array](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_array.asp) syntax.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort an array of javascript objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/how-to-sort-an-array-of-javascript-objects) or [Sorting objects in an array by a field value in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sorting-objects-in-an-array-by-a-field-value-in-javascript)

Comment: `myArray is an Object not an Array - does that change anything?` I'm afraid it is neither and is simply invalid syntax. Trying to run your code as is [**in jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HHcMD/) for example generates `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : ` You can see the error in the debugger's console log when running the fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

In Javascript, [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)s can **only** be declared with numeric keys and [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)s can be declared with alphanumeric keys (attributes).

It may help to take a look at Javascript's array [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method.

However, although there is not a way to declare an array with non-numeric keys, as icktoofay has pointed out, since arrays are a special type of object, it is **possible** to set non-numeric keys for arrays after they have been declared.

Comment: As an array is an object, it actually *can* have non-numeric keys, but there is no special syntax for them as there is in plain object literals and it is not treated specially by the array.

Comment: @icktoofay - Thanks for pointing out those details about arrays.

Comment: Sorry guys, see my edit.

Comment: @TheVasari - Take a look at some related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467129/sort-javascript-object-by-key , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947822/javascript-sort-objects , and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-javascript-object-by-property-value .

Comment: @Aiias, thank you, that first link was exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, that syntax is invalid: there is no way to set a key in an array literal. Additionally, while it is possible, you probably do not want an array with non-numeric properties; arrays are designed to hold numeric properties.

Even if those were corrected, properties in an object [have no defined iteration order](http://es5.github.com/#x12.6.4):

> The mechanics **and order** of enumerating the properties […] is not specified.

Sorting, by definition, affects the order; if there is no defined order in the first place, you cannot really change it.