# Create array of keys by sorting values

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, object

I have an object that looks like this

```
myList: {  
id1:{  
      ts:'2010-01-12T00:51:00',
      name:"roger"
     },  
id2:{  
      ts:'2011-01-12T05:22:00',
      name: "Tom"
  },  
id3:{  
      ts:'2013-01-12T11:32:00',
      name:"Jack"
  }
}
```

I know objects cant be sorted so i wanted to know how i can generate an array of just the keys,which are sorted according to the key "ts". I want this in descending order.

So the array for the above object will be [id3,id2,id1]

once i have this array i can make operations like this where arr is sorted array and myList is the object

```
for(var i=0:i<arr.length;i++)
{
alert(myList[arr[i]].name);
}
```

Comment: String comparison of dates?

Comment: As written, the ts values above are 1997, 1998 and 2000, but it seems doubtful that this is what's intended.

Comment: I am new to js so if you have a soln where i can generate such an array i would appreciate it

Comment: It would help to have more context. It seems likely that there is no reason for the outer object to not be an array, and if that's an option, the solution will be simpler.

Comment: You may want to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947822/javascript-sort-objects Also, string should have quotes around them or else it's just math at best.

Comment: You basically want a collection: `list=[{id:1,ts:'2010-01-12'},{id:2,ts:'2011-01-12'},...]`

Comment: I have edited to give more clarity on what i am trying to achieve

Comment: You still need quotes around the dates (and you probably really want them to be new Date('2010-01-12') also).

Comment: I have added quotes. Can someone tell me how to do this . Thanks i appreciate the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var keys = Object.keys(myList).sort(function(a, b) {
    if (myList[a].ts == myList[b].ts) {
        return 0;
    }
    return myList[a].ts < myList[b].ts ? 1 : -1;
});

console.log(keys);
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pWq2L/

Explanation:

1. First you export keys from the object: `Object.keys(myList)`
2. You sort using custom comparison function and in it you refer to the `.ts` attribute of the compared values. `a` and `b` are the keys of the compared elements

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 0):

Given this data structure, and assuming there is a good reason for it to not be an array:

```
var myList = {
  id1: {  
    ts: new Date('2010-01-12T00:51:00'),
    name: 'Roger'
  },
  id2: {  
    ts: new Date('2011-01-12T05:22:00'),
    name: 'Tom'
  },  
  id3:{  
    ts: new Date('2013-01-12T11:32:00'),
    name: 'Jack'
  }
}
```

We can create and sort an array like so:

```
var arr = [];
Object.keys(myList).forEach(function(item) {
  arr.push(myList[item]);
});
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.ts > b.ts ? -1 : a.ts < b.ts ? 1 : 0;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to extend `zerkms` solution is to work with an object augmented with smart properties. The versatile `reduce` comes in handy:

```
var result = keys.reduce(function(arr, k, i) {
    var item = {
      key: k,
      index: i,
      value: myList[k]
    };
    arr.push(item);
    return arr;
}, []);


//result:
[
  { index:0 , key: id3, value: {...} },
  { index:1 , key: id2, value: {...} },
  { index:2 , key: id1, value: {...} }
]
```

`reduce` is part of the ECMAScript 5th edition; so you may fill in some gap with a polyfill.

http://jsfiddle.net/pWq2L/3/